# get localstorage value and switch store in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have a function in utils that do this:

```
export function getUserRole() {
  return (
    localStorage.getItem('token') &&
    jwtDecode(localStorage.getItem('token')).role
  )
}
```

I call it in a component like so

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.role = getUserRole()
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.role) //admin, member

    return (
      <Provider store={this.role === 'member' ? store : adminStore}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div className="App">
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

how do I switch store here? Above code worked but will load the adminStore first then load store if the role is member. How can I prevent loading both store and adminStore into my app?

Answer (score 1):

Its because `componentDidMount` will get called after the initial rendering, and during the first rendering `this.role` will be undefined.

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.role = getUserRole()
    console.log(this.role);   // you will see the correct value
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.role) //undefined

    return (
      <div>Hello</div>
    )
  }
}
```

> Why its working with componentWillMount method?

Because that method get called before the initial rendering means before the render method triggered first time.

**Solution:**

You can call that method in the constructor, like this:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
       super()
       this.role = getUserRole()
    }
    .....
}
```

As per [Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount):

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted (inserted into the tree).
>
> componentWillMount is invoked just before mounting occurs. It is
>   called before render().

Comment: so the solution is put that at constructor correct? I've updated my question.

Comment: yea you can call that method in the constructor.

Comment: if you call that method in the constructor, then only one store will load, because constructor get called before the initial rendering. and during the first rendering that variable will have the correct value.

Comment: in my case store prop of Provider don't take empty store, that's the problem.

Comment: @Hoknimo can you explain more, not taking the empty store means? getting any error?

Comment: I will post a new question.

Comment: No, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50872598/switch-store-using-condition-in-render-using-redux Need help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first render occurs before the component mounts and componentDidMount is called, so the first render will indeed have undefined.

What you should do is add some logic to say:

`render() {
    if (this.role === null) {
      // Render loading state ...
    } else {
      // Render real UI ...
    }
  }`

Check [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#fetching-external-data) for more info.

Comment: I know the flow just that in my case I'm supplying a value to store prop of Provider