# Switch store using condition in render using redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

My application has 2 side, first side is the client app, second side is admin dashboard app. To make it DRY I decided to pass the store in the provider base on user role, so that I don't have to have 2 set of router.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.role = getUserRole() //get role from localstorage
  }

  renderSwitchProvider = store => (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <Switch>
            <Redirect exact from="/" to="/dashboard" />
            <Auth path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />

            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  )

  render() {
    if (this.role === 'member') {
      return this.renderSwitchProvider(store)
    } else if (this.role === 'admin') {
      return this.renderSwitchProvider(adminStore)
    }

    return null // problem is here
  }
}

export default App
```

But I got error of

```
Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(LoginForm)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(LoginForm)".
```

My getUserRole does this

```
export function getUserRole() {
  return (
    localStorage.getItem('token') &&
    jwtDecode(localStorage.getItem('token')).role
  )
}
```

Comment: Where do you get `store` and `adminStore` from? and when ?

Comment: That is just my redux store, usually you don't pass in different stores, it's most likely one store per app, but in my case I have 2 app now.

Comment: yeah. My question is either of those not null ?

Comment: @agent_hunt updated my question, added in getUserRole function, it can be null after the user has logged out. But passing null to store won't work, that's the problem now.

Comment: Yes. that is what is happening. Can you debug inside `renderSwitchProvider` what is the value of null ? The problem is not at the end of `render` function but null is getting passed to renderSwitchProvider

Comment: @agent_hunt getUserRole return undefined if no token found in the localstorage.

Comment: Shouldnt you be redirecting to login in that case ?

Comment: @agent_hunt this is my index.js, the router is wrapped within the Provider.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably from `getUserRole()` this is a blocking task and this returns a null and role should not be null.

My suggestion here would be to have an `APP` component which resolves the value from `getUserRole()` and returns an `Admin` or `User` component based on the result from `getUserRole()`

Remove redux store implementation from `App` component and place implementation in individual `Admin` or `User` components.

Comment: I know the issue, but this.role will have something after the user has logged in.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, there are two sides `client` and `admin`.

So,you can assume default value for you store implementation.

Assume, you always want to load `client` store by default.

then render should be,

```
render() {

    if (this.role === 'admin') {
      return this.renderSwitchProvider(adminStore)
    }else if(this.role === 'member'){

        return this.renderSwitchProvider(store)
    }



}
```

Comment: if I do a console.log() in client reducer, I can see the trigger even though I logged in as admin, is this good?

Comment: In admin case,there should be `role` value exists.It means your `getUserRole ` is not working properly

Comment: getUserRole return undefined when there's no token (after the user is logged out)

Comment: this will work, I'll keep this solution, I was over thinking.

Comment: my screen will be blank if you return `{}`